# Passing a token throughout my project in android

Tags: java, android

I want to use a TOKEN that I got from the server, this token expires, so if something happens on the way, and the server does not give me data, the token expired, I will send my user back to get a new token, though out my project in Android.

I have tried everything possible to my knowledge. I have read many answers related to the topic in StackOverFlow, but they do not give the right answer.

```
override fun onResponse(call: okhttp3.Call, response: Response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful && response != null){
                    val token = response.body()?.string()

                    this@MainActivity.runOnUiThread(Runnable {
                        val gsonToken = Gson()
                        val objectToken = gsonToken.fromJson(token, TokenObject::class.java)
                            token_extra = objectToken.token
                            saveDataPrefs(token_extra.toString())
                    })
                }
            }
```

I get the token with this code, but I want to use it like with classes as well as activity. I know how to use it between activity, I just pass it around with the Intent, but when I get to an Adapter, I do not know what to do. I want to send it to the adapter use it there till the end of the project.

Please, thank your. I am very new to this type of usage in Android.

Comment: make sure you have store the token properly in Shared Preference

Comment: You can simply pass the token to the adapter or any other class as a constructor parameter, i.e., `new MyAdapter(token)`.

Comment: mr.Joe, that is dope!!

Comment: What's wrong with this solution? Properly structured code should be unaware of framework as much as possible. That's why it's ok to inject such data to other components.

Comment: "That is dope" means it is awesome. I just tried that and it worked for me. Maybe Googling the meaning would have been better. Thank you!!

Comment: Make that an answer. I just do not like to use SharedPreference as the two others are saying down here.

Answer (score 1):

You can store token to the `SharedPreferences` (just like Ashish answered) but, Activity, Fragment, and Adapter should be used just for presenting data to the user and not for handling this stuff.

Currently from what I see this network request/response is handled inside `MainActivity`, so you need to send a token to all screens manually.

You should move this logic outside of views and handle token in a separate place.  Consider using some singleton where you can handle all data, or even better, read about software architectures and try to integrate the best architecture that suits to you into your project (MVVM or MVP).
Then you can store the token in a sharedPrefs, database or whatever you like in one place. Also from this place, you can obtain, process this token and notify views about change through listeners, lambdas or liveData. In this way, you will avoid passing token through all views or initialize sharedPrefs inside views.

Maybe it is hard at the beginning but later as the application grows your life will be easier.